# Team flag dialog doesn't have the same padding other flag dialogs do

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, old-teams

When trying to flag a team, the padding around the flag options is either nonexistent or cuts off very close to the edge of the container:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Styling conflict - it'll be fixed in the next build. Thanks!